# Alamofire 4 sends method as POST but server reads it GET

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a very weird problem here, using Alamofire 4 Swift 4 Xcode 9.1

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
    manager.session.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

    let request = manager.request(
        url,
        method: HTTPMethod.post,
        parameters: [:])
```

But server replies with method not allowed because it reads it as GET, however, if I change HTTPMethod.put or .delete or any other method, the server reads it correctly, the problem is with post specifically!

By debugging Alamofire's class 'SessionManager', specially the following method:

```
open func request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
```

The method here is correct, POST, so it's just fine before it goes out the application, what's wrong?

Comment: As a sanity check, I would do this through a NSURLSession, or through an app like Postman or HTTPRequestor.

Comment: Yes doing that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was adding '/' at the end of the URL that was causing this.